# Multiple-hypothesis correction with many weakly significant p-values

Tags: multiple-comparisons

Let's assume we did multiple comparisons in a study and got a bunch of weakly significant p-values at the 0.05 level (e.g., 0.041, 0.042, ... 0.049) and a single non-significant one (0.1). Now, if we apply any of the common multiple-testing corrections (Bonferroni, Benjamini-Hochberg, etc.), this "kills" the significance in all the cases.

While it makes sense mathematically, it seems it is quite problematic with regards to interpretation - obviously, *some* of the comparisons may have rejected the null hypothesis wrongly, but it's unlikely that all such rejections are spurious.

Is this a general issue for multiple testing corrections, or is there a method that would handle such cases more intuitively?

Comment: To pitch the answer at the right level, please can you clarify what do you already know about the actual quantities (e.g. family-wise error rate, the false discovery rate) these multiple-testing correction procedures aim to control, and the quantities (e.g. Type II errors) that these procedures have no guarantees on?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I don't think we can infer this from the data directly - basically, we don't know a priori. The FDR I used as input to the Benjamini-Hochberg correction was 0.05.

Comment: Absolutely makes sense that it is difficult to infer how many hypothesis is actually true or not - my comment is more an attempt to understand whether you are aware what the 0.05 FWER / FDR actually mean (both mathematically and intuitively), and how the mentioned procedures does not control false negative rate (which may be what you are seeing when the procedure "kills" the significance). Will expand as an answer when I get the time.

Comment: Aaah, haha, right, that's a very good point, actually - I forgot about Type 2 errors!

I just thought it's quite an interesting phenomenon to ask about - because people often use the correction by default, but particularly for relatively low-power studies (which are very common in my field), this can inflate t2 error rate in a seemingly counterintuitive way - but somehow without your comment I failed to phrase this clearly.

Thanks again!